# Getting an error, text.match error when no results exist

Tags: actionscript-3, text, input

I have code that looks like this

```
if (consearch.text.match(/kau$/).length >= 0)
{ 
trace("test"); 
}
```

which works fine if consearch.text value ends with "kau"
unfortunately when it does not end with "kau" I get a 1009 error

Am I missing something?? Not sure why its giving me this error

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Have you considered using String.contains(String) instead?

Comment: i need to find the phrase "kau" at only the END of the input text, I dont know of anyway to search for only the end of the string with String.contains

Comment: [Give this a try](https://github.com/as3/as3-utils/blob/master/src/utils/string/endsWith.as)

Comment: @DodgerThud unfortunately it's incomplete

Comment: Is it? Doesn't look like it, but if you say so. [How about GSkinner instead?](http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2007/04/free_extension.html)

Comment: @Koden just cut/paste that function into your code and call it as such: `if (endsWith(consearch.text, "kau")) { trace "test"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont know how to use packages then use it like this, this is part of the code link @DodgerThud suggests,

```
function endsWith(input:String, suffix:String):Boolean {
    return (suffix == input.substring(input.length - suffix.length));
}
if (endsWith(consearch.text,"kau"))
{ 
    trace("test"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that you got an answer, but I'll try to explain why you got that error ?

So you got that error because [`String.match()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match()) returns an array **ONLY** if there is at least one substring in the string (`consearch.text`) that matches the specified pattern (`/kau$/`) otherwise it's returning **null**, and that's why that error is fired when your text didn't contain `kau` at its end.

If you want always to use `RegExp`, you can do it like this for example :

```
if (/kau$/.test(consearch.text))
{ 
    trace('test'); 
}
```

Hope that can help.